# The end is near, and no one can stop it

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, knowledge

I must warn you of what's coming, but I can't say what it is or I risk death. Please, I beg of you, figure out the clues I have left and help me save the world.

> On this dreaded occasion, we must mourn;
> Our electronics, they have failed to warn.
>
> Name we cannot mutter without its wrath,
> You will die when you're strewn along its path.
>
> Your pleas for help will go unheard;
> Worse than the führer, what have we stirred?
>
> The sun will die if we don't know what to do;
> Our eight-legged friend, he is our only clue.

Hint

> I̥̖̲͠t͖̳̦͉͓̦'ś ̷̹̜̥͉͙̩a̕ͅḻ͢r̫̞͠e̲̭̣͍̦̺a͕͖͚̫dy ̠̮̥̤̗̲s̛̹̞̱̩̻̠̬t͔̬̞a̦r͈͚t͓͇͇̩͈̮̠i̛̩n̨̪ͅg͕̜͔̤̦̘̰ ͍t͚̭̭͍o͏ ͙ͅt̛͈a͉̣̞͎̹̺͡k̸̺̹̲̲̱̲e͚̙̪̙̟ ͚͙̰͎ov̱̼̣͕͠e̸̜̳r͚̮.̫̻̜̬̗̻ ̴̗̫̦̝ͅI̱̫̖̬ ̷̰̲̣̞͍̱c̳͜a͙̲̭͕͚͚̺͡n͖̜̥̫ ͓̰o̶̦̻ͅn̪̖͠l̡y͎͇̱̙̮̟̗ ͟g̳̱̤̖i̜̥͇̲͎̠͘v̬̝͟e̦͈ ̼͎̰̪̲̤t̮̻̙h̥̝̻͘is̞̬̜̮̪ ̭̯̹͉̳͜o̬̦̪n̷̥̤̬̼͓̯̘e̺̠̺̠̯̯̳͡ ͇͓͇̺̗̼͍la͍̺̞̠̩̱̞s̢̹̖͙̳̰̱̰t͉̥̥͓̱̀ ̼̝͙̤̱̯̘c̺̭̦͘l̺͍̰̬͘u͇̩̬͟e̥͚͉.̟͚͍ ̛̖̜Th̵̩e͍̪͈̟̙͈̱͠ ̶͔͔͕͔̫̼c̩̠̠̝͔̩͝l̜̖͔̼͎̺̣͢u͈͝e̪ ͙̙̯̮̀į̯̦̙̤̘s̲͓ ̘̗̬͙̺̜aͅͅ ҉̜̬͙̳̦̭̹ẉ̴͓͚ͅo͔r͖̙͟d̬̞̻̠̖ ̫̳̞in̺̭̣̺̭̟̠͡s̺̖̳͓i̻̯̝d̮̦͕͉͓͕ͅe̢͇̻̥ ͍̯̜͇t͙͕̥̯͉̀ͅh͕̱̩͖̟̤ͅe͓ ͈̘͔r͎͇̜̤̦̦i̢d̹̖͎̲͢d̦̫͉͍ļ̲̭e̮̲̫̳̞̫.̦͍̤͍̪̥

Hint 2

> C̸̺̝̖͕̫͙͚̦͎̦̙͔͚̰̹̟̭̱a҉҉̧̹̲͈̠͇͇̲͝n͏̸̛͎̱̳̬̰̬̺͠͡ͅ ͏̧̪̥̬͎̻̺̤̜̲͝͡ọ̡̨̟̠̫͙͈̺̬̰̫̦̯̀͘ń̛͢҉̫̰͈̞̹͎̮͕̱͍l̶̛̺̭͕͍͙̣̫̙͓͕y̧̩͈͉̩̥̮̤̩̠̫̞̘̣̳͓͓̳̗͞͡ͅ ̷̳̩̬̤̻͉̳̖̻́͢͡͡ś̶̨͇̤̰̲̜͕̼̹̱͙̫͔͚͇̤͉̀͘à̸̴̡̗͇̺̜͙̭͕̙y̧͟͟͏̜͓͓̬͕͖̖̖͕̭͇̠͓̼ ̨͟͏̗̬̣̜̝̜̘̭͈̪͕̩́ͅÌ̡̱̳͚̪͉̭͔͡ ̧̣͓͔̹̙͓̱͙ṃ̸͈͉̼̲̭͓̰̞̯̪̘̀o̶̱̙̲͉̤̮̭͘͘͟͞ͅr̴̸̝̠̘͕̤̪̻͉͍̭̮̀é̡̨̛͍̫̬̥͍̦̥̙̼̤͍̖̩͔̭ͅ ͘͏̨̛͉̫̙̭̥̖͍̪̯͔̖͔̼̯ͅͅͅͅw҉̕҉͎̥͎̲͍̙͎̼͔͎̺͇͘͠o̷̵̝̬̜͔̮̻̱͔̫̗͓̠̻̹̺̹͇͇͝͠ͅr̸̷̢̖̻͎̩͚̜͚̺̝͕̼̪̲͕̝d̙̻͍̰̲̫̠͓̻̮͍̙͔̪͖͕̕͢,̨̪̳̜͇̪̭͜͡ ̴̖̳̭̥̹̗͚͉̖͈̜̫̗͔͍̭̳̟͘c̶̸̨͈̻̳̣̩̫̜̼̯͇̻̞̫̩̩͡é̛̼̫̞̣͉̮͢͞p̶̢̧͢҉̦͓̖͎͎̯̳̲̯h͢͏̡̤͔̻͈̭̤̲͙̟a̶̷͓̱̬̼̬͉̮͉̟͓̙̝̯̞̯̣̦͘ͅl̛͖̫̦̯o̝̳̰̰͘͝p̜͉͕̱͞o̴̢͓̖̪̜͎̬̟̱͎̞̥͈̝̕͝͞d̵̢̻̼͚̹̩͎̹̥̹̺͙͘͜ͅ.̸̹̱̮͍̞̥̝̼͈̙͙̘̪̟̖͚̥̀̕͜͞ͅ

Hint 3

> R̂ͨ͂̎ͥ̽̅͐́̑͐ͭͭͪ͗̓ͨ̓ͬ͜͏̨̙̮͖͓͢i̡̖̯̳̮̣̗͕͔̘͗̓̋͒ͬ̈͒̏ͯ̿̓͡ͅg̴̵͈̫͎̜̜̙̗̲̭͖̫̘̪͙̝̔̑́̒͐ͫ̔͑̓́ͅh͛̋̄͒̽ͬ͗̔̋̓̎ͫ̂ͣ͒ͤ̇̂̚͏̸̡̬̗̻̞̹͉̱͖͈̹͔̪͢ṯ̴̻̭͕̮̀̉̐͑ͮ̔̔̈ͪͨ̊̔̈͊ͨͨ́ ̸̡͈̤͇̥͖̞̰̳̰̪͎̒̅̎͂ͬͥ͗͆ͭ̾͆͋ͮ̀̚͘o͉̜̼̩͙̮̝̹̥̩͇̰̥̘͎͚͋ͮ͗͑̀̐̋̋̇̑̂͠f̮͉̟͕̮͎̝̣̙ͮ̈ͭ̋̈ͭ̃̐̂͋͒̉ͩ͐̚͢͝ ̴̡̛̛͎͔̺̱̹̰̠͍̠̻͆̈̿̾̂̆ͩ̕O̸̷͂͛̽͊̇ͯ̌ͣͨ̍̊̇ͥ̃͋̕͏̦͙͉̺͔͎c̷͎̻͔̭̗̰̟̈́̉̀̇̉͆͑̈̎̀ͅť̈͐̊͏͖̰͍͈̝̝̥̫̦̱͓͟ơ̴̞͈̟̑̋ͭ́͘͡p̸̷̵͖̰̻̩͖̰̫̜̤̲̭̥̝̫̜̄̽̆̂͛͆̉̑͊̌̕͜ͅͅͅŭ̸̡̲̭̪̬͉͉̗͕̤̝̱ͥ̌ͪ͒̏͌́s̸̠̗̖̘̯̩̙͇͖̹͕͐̾ͧ̄͗͐̑ͅ

Final Hint

> Ą͇̝̺̞̳͚̫̆ͬ͊̽ç̼̫͎̝̺̱̠̫͉͚̜̟̲̩̗̪̼̂͌̐̔̓̆̽ͭ̉̎ͮͮͨ̐͗ͦ̌̓̽͘ř̷ͥ̍̓͌ͩ̏̀̎͑ͧͪ̾̿̈͛ͩ҉̡̧̤͔͎̯̖͉̲̥̳̤͈̥̫͞ơ̶̶̺̲̺̩̘̇͂̑̒̏̓͆͊̄͝ş͋̈́ͫͧͥͥ͒͏͉͍̤̝͙̝͈̩̲ţ̸̨̛̬̯̜̬̲͍̩͉̱̤̩̹̥̱͕̞͎̒̋̎̓̾͑͆ǐ̹͍͕͇͚̪̪̟̙̫̯̠͖̀͛̆͒ͬ̏̒̑́̋͠c͚̬͚̱͎̭̞̻̰̫͇̮̝̠̥͙̬̓̓̋̍ͩ̆ͮ͢͡ͅ

Comment: Is our eight legged friend definitely a "he"? Because I'm thinking of a black widow, which would be female, otherwise my guess does not work.

Comment: Our eight legged friend can be male or female, I suppose.

Comment: Also, I guess you could call them arms or appendages if you'd like.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know is the last quarter related to the rot13( gneqvtenqr, sbe ur jvyy fheivir gur qrngu bs bhe fha )?

Comment: @BlakeSteel, not at all.

Comment: A curious result, not likely an intentional clue, is that the third words of the first four lines create the statement "Dreaded, they cannot die". Sets the tone, though.

Comment: @cpcodes, If I could upvote that comment more, I would.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't get all the clues but you must have summoned

> Cthulhu

Our eight legged friend, he is our only clue.

> Cthulhu has an octopus-like head

Hint 2:

> If you read carefully, it says "Can only say 1 more word: cephalopod"

Hints:

> The clue is a word inside the riddle, the word is octopus
> On this dreaded **o**ccasion, we must mourn;
> Our ele**c**tronics, they have failed to warn.
> Name we cannot mutter wi**t**hout its wrath,
> Y**o**u will die when you're strewn along its path.
> Your **p**leas for help will go unheard;
> Worse than the f**ü**hrer, what have we stirred?
> The **s**un will die if we don't know what to do;
> Our eight-legged friend, he is our only clue.
> Right of Octopus, it spells Cthulhu
> On this dreaded o**c**casion, we must mourn;
> Our elec**t**ronics, they have failed to warn.
> Name we cannot mutter wit**h**out its wrath,
> Yo**u** will die when you're strewn along its path.
> Your p**l**eas for help will go unheard;
> Worse than the fü**h**rer, what have we stirred?
> The s**u**n will die if we don't know what to do;
> Our eight-legged friend, he is our only clue.

The hints also remind me of [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6239991) because

> Parsing HTML with regex is sometimes know as "The Call of Cthulhu".

Comment: I mean, you're not wrong, but at the same time, I'd like you to figure out all the clues before I accept it.

Comment: Since you've come so far. I'd search for the word the hint leads to inside the puzzle (You've already mentioned what word it is, not the answer but the other word). You may be surprised what you find.

Comment: Because of the "Name we cannot mutter without its wrath" line, I'm more inclined to think that the poem refers to rot13(Unfghe), especially since the eight legged clue is referred to as a friend, rather than the cause of the threat.

Comment: @cpcodes Actually, the answer is correct. I'd just like the hints to be solved before I accept it.

Comment: Bounty is for the hints to be solved?

Comment: @ManojKumar, yes the bounty is for the hints to be solved, and the clues in the riddle.

Comment: It seems I accidentally tapped to downvote this answer, and it’s now too late to change it . Sorry, you didn’t deserve a downvote, I’d give an upvote if it would let me

Comment: @PatrickL I edited a misspelling in the answer, so when that correction is accepted you'll be able to change your vote.

Comment: I'm going to set the rest of the answer myself and mark this answer as accepted

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's the Dread Lord

> [image]

since you can't say its name

> No, **really**, [you *can't* say it *at all*](http://grognardia.blogspot.com/2011/08/loevcraftian-pedantry.html). The human throat is incapable of making the requisite noises and ['Cthulhu'—(inexplicably glossed by Lovecraft](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/698781/hp-lovecraft-explains-how-pronounce-cthulhu) as ["khlûl'-hloo": /'qlʊlhluː/ or /'xlʊlhluː/](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iR2wTq55ZWU)—is merely an approximation. (The Old Ones themselves don't even speak vocally; they use transmitted thought.) The clue "I can't say... it... or I risk death" is a misattribution of Lovecraft's description of the dread name [Azathoth](https://lovecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Azathoth). There's a bit in ["The Call of Cthulhu"](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/cc.aspx) where the spells which hold the Old Ones in check need to be undone by others (their human cultists), but that can't involve actually saying their names correctly since... y'know... *we can't*.

and electronics are no good in its presence

> This isn't really canon since the ships that land on Rlyeh don't have any problems with their radios or with getting its coordinates but "[The Whisperer in Darkness](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/wid.aspx)" does say that Cthulhu and his kind have their electrons all wrong.

and it's worse than Hitler

> He wants a general genocide of all noncultists, not just a 'ethnic cleansing'.

and the sun is at risk

> "The Whisperer in the Dark" implies star-born Cthulhu was responsible for the (super)novae of half the stars.

and an eight-legged friend is a clue

> There is no octopus friend of ours but images and spawn of Cthulhu are described as having "octopus-like" heads; Cthulhu himself is said to have an "awful squid-head with writhing feelers". He's usually given an octopoid head with a variable number of tentacles.

and there's Z̆͋̂̈́aͮͣ͑̐͆ͦ̂lͨ̔ͩ̽̀̉̉̎͂͆͌ͩ̚g͂̽̒̇̔o͒ͥ͊̑͑͒̽ͬ̌͆̓ͣ̚ tĕ̆̈́͒ͥ̈́ͦ̒͒ͦx̃̊̋͂̔̋ͥ͊́̿ͭͫ͐ͩẗ́̓̍ͣ̀͆͌̐̓̈̇̈̂ͫ̾͋̌ in the extra clues.

> which [got their name from a SomethingAwful knock-off of the Cthulhu mythos](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/zalgo).

On the other hand,

> There is no actual acrostic. The letters OONYYWTO have nothing to do with Lovecraft's mythos even if you imagine it's an anagram. It'd be *very* clever if the poem had an octametric clue (even if that's eight *feet*, not eight legs) or had something to do with [the old Chinese *baguwen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight-legged_essay), but that's not the case. @cpcodes saw that the first four lines' third words are, "dreaded, they cannot die" but 3/3rd has nothing to do with anything and the next four lines have nothing sensible in them. The first four lines have 10 feet each, but the next four go 8, 9, 11, 11. That also doesn't seem to have any reason.
> It's probably not OP's fault, though. Cthulhu is known to scramble the brains of those who think about him too much.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> some kind of virus?

since

> the text in clues got corrupt look like it has been affected by some kind of virus. the riddle tells us it is strewn etc.

and cephalopod clue is for

> cephalopods are immune against viruses and vaccinations are useless for them OR some viruses do look like cephalopods

this may be incorrect or lacking of course but I wanted to give my guess a shot

Comment: That's clever reasoning. Unfortunately, this isn't the correct answer. You may want to look at the first hint more closely.

Comment: is the 'word inside the riddle' hidden like encrypted or distributed? or is it formed as regular word and clearly shown?

Comment: I̛t́'̡s d͘i̵str̴ib͞ut҉e̶d o͏n̛e ͜l͡et͟te͝r͝ at̡ ̶a͘ t͟i̶m͘e ́įn ̷the ̨r͞i͠dd̶l͟e.͞ I͠f Į ͡di͟rectly p͘ut͝ ͞it̶ ҉in̷, ̧it͘ ̕wo̵u͜ld ̸b̡e̷ ͟sure ͞to͟ kill m̨e.